# TYPO3 fal upload image with alt-text

Tags: typo3, extbase, fal

I can do uploads after following a few tutorials like this one:
http://t3-developer.com/extbase-fluid/extensions-erweitern/fal-in-eigenen-extensions/fal-dateiupload-im-frontend/

But I miss two fields. When doing a FAL upload of a media file. How to add **alternate** and **link**?

Answer (score 0):

try look at this. Maybe it can help:
https://forge.typo3.org/issues/56884